# Android Fragment Tabs - Increase tab width onTabSelected

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity, android-tabs, fragment-tab-host

Ive been debating whether to use text for my tabs or icons bc i cant fit both on smaller devices. So I was considering attempting to make it so that when a tab is selected the selected tabs width increases giving it room for a icon as well as text. Is this possible/practical?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a few weeks since your question, and not a direct answer, more an idea that I use for my multi-screen apps:

Rather than having an image which appears on the current tab, have a simple test that if the screen size is smaller than your limit, it doesn't add the images in, but if it's a large enough screen it puts in the icons

As screen real estate is limited on small screen phones, putting the icon in would force the tabs to be large enough to hold the icons, so you might as well show the icons all of the time

I hope this helps make your decision on how to lay out the screen on various sizes of phone